# Primitive elements in $k[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

I need to find all primitives element of $k[x]$ with the coalgebra structure: $\Delta(x)=1\otimes x+x\otimes 1$ and $\epsilon(x)=0$. If char($k$) is zero, for me it's clear that, within the basis $\{x^{n} |n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, the only possibility for an elment to be primitive is when $n=1$, so for x. But how can I be sure that for a generic polynomial $p(x)$, there won't be cancellation of terms in $\Delta(p(x))$ so that it is a primitive element too? 
Thank you, any hint will be appreciated !

Comment: To see that I understand your question: we are given that $$\Delta(x) = 1\otimes x + x\otimes 1,$$ and we want to show that if $$\Delta(p(x) ) =1\otimes p(x) + p(x)\otimes 1, $$ then  $p(x) = x$. Correct? (with the proviso that char $k$ = $0$, as you state)

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: What about a $c x$, for $c\in k$? $\Delta (c x ) = c \Delta (x)$...

Comment: even kx is primitive, but I tried with a $p(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+....+a_{0}$ and I don't know how to show that it cannot be primitive if $n\geq2$..and $a_{0}\neq0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $p(x)= a_0 +\cdots +a_nx^n$. Write $y = 1\otimes x$, and $z =x \otimes 1$. Since $\Delta$ is a ring-homomorphism, $\Delta (p (x ) ) =  p(\Delta x) =  p ( y + z)$. Therefore
$$ \Delta (p (x ) ) = a_0 + a_1( y + z) + a_2( y^2+ 2 yz + z^2) + \cdots.$$
For this to equal $$ (a_0 + a_1y+ a_2 y^2 + a_3 y^3+ \cdots) + (a_0 + a_1 z+ a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 + \cdots), $$
the coefficients on both side have to be equal, as $\{y^kz^l\}$  forms a basis for $k[y,z] $. As the characteristic of $k$ is zero... OK?